# How to transform Map<String, List<String>> into Files by Key Value

Tags: java, file, hash, hashmap, guava

I have a data-structure of `Map<String, List<String>>` that follows the following code:

`for (int i = 0; i < al_dwpi_par.size(); i++) {
            if (!hash_features_dwpi_dc.containsKey(al_dwpi_par.get(i).getGA())) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(al_dwpi_par.get(i).getDC());`

```
            hash_features_dwpi_dc.put(al_dwpi_par.get(i).getGA(), list);
        } else {
            hash_features_dwpi_dc.get(al_dwpi_par.get(i).getGA()).add(al_dwpi_par.get(i).getDC());
        }
    }`
```

This creates a Hash `<key>,<List>` where my list stores in each position information related to that key. Apparently that hash has no errors.

I'm trying to create a file where each element in that list will be a line related to that Key. Imagine that one element of that Hash is:
`<1997>,<ball, house, ball, monkey, light, banana`>. My file should be in the end something like 1997.results.txt and each line:

`ball 
house 
ball 
monkey 
light 
banana`

I have tried to iterate through my Hash and some other things but was not successful. Even tried to work with Guava (as suggest by some similar posts), not good too.

Any idea/example/suggestion is more than welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for

```
map.forEach((name, lines) -> {
    try {
       Files.write(Paths.get(name + ".results.txt"), lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // do whatever
    }
});
```

...assuming Java 8 is available.

Comment: Java 8 is indeed available, I shall try it.
Thank you.

Comment: Worked like a glove. :-)
First time that I saw this construction in JAVA

Comment: @brso05 don't know who downvoted, is it possible to check that?

Comment: Not possible to know who downvoted. Kind of awful behavior since this is a very optimum solution and a nice use of the Java 8 features.

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer using Java 8. Here I come with my own approach, a little bit longer, hope it helps you or could be useful as a reference if Java 8 is not available. Use of NIO it is also useful :).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Given this information
    Map<String, List<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> valuesForKey = new ArrayList<String>();
    valuesForKey.add("ball");
    valuesForKey.add("house");
    valuesForKey.add("ball");
    valuesForKey.add("monkey");
    valuesForKey.add("light");
    valuesForKey.add("banana");

    dataMap.put("1997", valuesForKey);

    //I'd like to create a file:
    createTextFileFromMap(dataMap);
}

private static void createTextFileFromMap(Map<String, List<String>> dataMap) throws IOException {
    //Iterate the map to generate the number of files according to the items in your map
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entries : dataMap.entrySet()) {
        String filePath = "data/" + entries.getKey() + ".results.txt";//Generate a file with name based on key
        String formattedValues = getFormattedData(entries.getValue());//Format the list values to a line separated list
        BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePath)));//Use a BufferedWriter
        bwriter.write(formattedValues);//Write the content
        bwriter.close();//Close the writer
    }
}

//Just a method that will iterate over your list to put your strings of the list in a single String in which values will be separated by lines
private static String getFormattedData(List<String> valueList) {
    StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : valueList) {
        sbuilder.append(word).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    return sbuilder.toString();
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Good alternative for non-Java-8. Thanks !